# XCode 4.2 build failed with error code 1 (no issues), but works on XCode 3.2.6

Tags: iphone, ios, build

I have this weird problem.
I'm trying to move to XCode 4.2, so I opened my project in XCode 4.2 and tried to build my project for iOS device. The build failed with no issues or any explanation. The weirdest thing is that the project is built with no problems for the Simulator and on XCode 3.2.6 (device and simulator).

This is the result I get when building:

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

With no other issues.
I checked my Bundle Identifier and Product name and they do not contain illegal characters (only a-zA-Z).
I Also tried building with Apple's LLVM 3.0 which got the same result.
Provisioning profile was also double-checked.

Is there anything else that could cause that? What can I do?

edit:
Here are the details from the log:

```
    Ld /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dyvsuphvmlexzzghpgbnkfzmtqas/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp normal armv7
    cd /Users/user/Documents/Projects/MyApp
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.0
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dyvsuphvmlexzzghpgbnkfzmtqas/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -LRouteMe/MapView -LRouteMe/MapView/GTM -LRouteMe/MapView/Map -LRouteMe/MapView/UnitTesting -LRouteMe/MapView/Map/Cache.xcdatamodel -LRouteMe/MapView/Map/FMDB -LRouteMe/MapView/Map/Resources -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dyvsuphvmlexzzghpgbnkfzmtqas/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dyvsuphvmlexzzghpgbnkfzmtqas/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyApp.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -all_load -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dyvsuphvmlexzzghpgbnkfzmtqas/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libMapView.a -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework Foundation -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -lsqlite3.0 -lstdc++.6 -framework CoreData -framework StoreKit -framework CoreMotion -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dyvsuphvmlexzzghpgbnkfzmtqas/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try viewing the detailed build log and posting it? Right-click on the issue in the issue navigator (command-4) and choose "Reveal in log" to get to the build log.

Comment: Hrm. That's not much information. There seems to be lots of people with this problem for various reasons. Try cleaning the build folder?

Comment: I did...unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: When we upgraded to Xcode 4.2, some of our code caused LLVM to crash, but not GCC. You might try omitting some libraries or .m files to see if you can isolate the location of the issue.

Comment: When you have clicked on your project or target in xcode's navigator, have you done a `Validate Settings` (in the bottom of the right window)? Maybe something essential is missing, you can correct it there.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the solution! (thanks to Jesse Rusak's advice)
I used CloudMade's library for displaying a map. This library probably caused the problem.
I removed the library and removed all the library and header search paths to it.
After that I changed the base SDK of CloudMade's projects to "Latest iOS" and re-added the library to my project again. Re-added it to the library and header search path and thats it! it worked!

Thanks everyone!